# Passing a field to javascript and evaluate

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web form with several text boxes.  I want to evaluate the default value in a text box and when user clicks on the field I want to clear it out.  This is helping to reduce space on a form.

The below gives error message "Microsoft JScript Runtime error: object required.

Javascript:

```
function validateKeyword(f, flg, val) {
    switch (flg) {
        case 0: if (document.getElementById(f).value == val) { document.getElementById(f).value = ''; } break;
        case 1: if (document.getElementById(f).value == '') { document.getElementById(f).value = val; } break;
    }
}
```

ASP.NET textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox maxlength="150"  runat="server" name="First_Name" value="First Name" class="frmsel2" onfocus="javascript:validateKeyword('first_name',0,'First Name');" onblur="javascript: validateKeyword('first_name',1,'First Name');" alt="First Name" title="First Name" id="first_name"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting this in the Page_Load event in the code behind.  (Made edits to use constant values).

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string FormDefaFirstName = "First Name";
    private const string FormDefaLastName = "Last Name";

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        first_name.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript: if(this.value=='" + FormDefaFirstName + "') this.value='';");
        first_name.Attributes.Add("onfocusout", "javascript: if(this.value=='') this.value='" + FormDefaFirstName + "';");
        last_name.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript: if(this.value=='" + FormDefaLastName + "') this.value='';");
        last_name.Attributes.Add("onfocusout", "javascript: if(this.value=='') this.value='" + FormDefaLastName + "';");


    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        first_name.Text = "First Name";
        last_name.Text = "Last Name";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5 I think you can use **placeholder**.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Not using HTML 5 at this time, but a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

reference your ID in javascript by using

```
document.getElementById(<%= first_name.ClientID %>).value = ''
```

Comment: although actually, I don't know if you can do this from within an ASP control.